# Flutter Firebase OTP verification fails even though both sent and entered OTP are the same

Tags: flutter, firebase, authentication, firebase-authentication, flutter-dependencies

I am trying to implement OTP verification in my Flutter app using Firebase, but I am facing an issue where the verification fails even though both the sent and entered OTP are the same.

I am using the following function to verify the OTP:

```
void verifyOtp({
    required BuildContext context,
    required String verificationId,
    required String userOtp,
    required Function onSuccess,
  }) async {
    _isLoading = true;
    notifyListeners();
    try {
      PhoneAuthCredential creds = PhoneAuthProvider.credential(
          verificationId: verificationId, smsCode: userOtp);
      User? user = (await _firebaseAuth.signInWithCredential(creds)).user!;
      print('signwithcredential passed');
      if (user != null) {
        _uid = user.uid;
        onSuccess();
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (e) {
      print('failed Userotp: $userOtp');
      showSnackBar(context, e.message.toString());
      _isLoading = false;
      notifyListeners();
    }
  }
```

The error I am getting is "FirebaseAuthException: sms code has expired please resend the verification code to verify again."

I am new to Flutter and Firebase, so any help in fixing this problem would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Here are couple of things I have found maybe they will work:

- Check the Firebase Console to ensure that the phone number being verified is correctly set up and that the SMS code is being sent to the right number.
- Make sure that the phone number is being passed in the correct format.
- FirebaseAuthException is being caught correctly. Make sure the message inside the catch block is being logged or displayed to the user.
- Ensure that the dependencies and packages are correctly installed and imported.

Comment: i've verified above all points. Its all proper . Both shared code and sent code are matching, exact error code is I/flutter ( 9598): error on firebaseAuthexception: [firebase_auth/session-expired] The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.

Answer (score 0):

The solution is itself an error you are getting. **You have to enter the code before it expire.** Try to verify the otp as soon as you get the code as it's saying "**I/flutter ( 9598): error on firebaseAuthexception: [firebase_auth/session-expired] The sms code has expired. Please re-send the verification code to try again.** ".

Comment: i did same for multiple times , each time i kept getting this error, even I added timeout still same error occurred.